# How to add in layer a upload image

Tags: konvajs, angular7

I would like to know how to add in image.src a upload image. 
I know that with *convas* i do *image.src = event.target.result* but it don't work.

**ts**

```
 onFileSelected(event){
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var stage: Konva.Stage;  
    var box: Konva.Rect;

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function()
    {    
      var img = new Konva.Image({ image: image });
      stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: image.width,
        height: image.height
      });
      layer.add(img);
      stage.add(layer); 
    }
    image.src = '' /* Image to put event.target.result */;
  }
```

**html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="image/*"> <br><br>

<div id="container" style="border: 2px solid red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample code looks basically functional. Open your browser dev tools (F12) and see if here are any messages or errors. I suspect cross-origin issues - search SO or Google for cross-origin for resolutions.

I can't give you a working angular example, nor even a working plain JS example that uses a file select because my Chrome browser insists I cannot load local files to this website. Anyway, the snippet below uses the change event of a select box in the same way that you would for a file select. It is based around the intention of your code.

```js
$('#daFile').on('change', function(e){
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container'})
    
    var image = new Image();
    
    var path = $(this).val(); // jquery way of retreiving new path
    
    image.onload = function()
    {    
      var img = new Konva.Image({ image: image });
      stage.size({width: image.width, height: image.height});
      layer.add(img);
      stage.add(layer); 
      stage.draw();
    }
    image.src = path;
  })
  
  setTimeout( function(){$('#daFile')
    .val('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSo4z.jpg')
    .trigger('change');
    }, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>
<div>
Select a file 
<select id='daFile'>
<option value='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awa0C.png'>Nosey dog</option>
<option value='https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSo4z.jpg'>Snow dog</option>
</select>
</div>  
<div id='container' style="display: inline-block; width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```